# ASP.net MVC 5 : Extend IdentityUser class to use My User Entity Class

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5, entity-framework-6, asp.net-identity

My UserManager Class in Asp.net MVC 5 is of below type

```
public UserManager<ApplicationUser<MyUser>> UserManager { get; private set; }
```

At run time type is ;

```
{Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.UserManager<app.Models.ApplicationUser<MyCustom.DataAccessLayer.MyUser>>}
```

When I am executing findAsync to authenticate.

```
var user = await UserManager.FindAsync(model.UserName, model.Password);
```

Then exception System.InvalidOperationException is thrown. Because it is not looking for MyUser entity, its look for ApplicationUser1 entity.

```
The entity type ApplicationUser1 is not part of the model for the current context.
   at System.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalContext.UpdateEntitySetMappingsForType(Type entityType)
   at System.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalContext.GetEntitySetAndBaseTypeForType(Type entityType)
   at System.Data.Entity.Internal.Linq.InternalSet1.Initialize()
   at System.Data.Entity.Internal.Linq.InternalSet1.get_InternalContext()
   at System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DbQuery1.System.Linq.IQueryable.get_Provider()
   at System.Linq.Queryable.Where[TSource](IQueryable1 source, Expression1 predicate)
   at Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework.UserStore1.FindByNameAsync(String userName)
   at Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.UserManager1.<FindByNameAsync>d__d.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter1.GetResult()
   at Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.UserManager1.<FindAsync>d__15.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
```

Answer (score 1):

Are you overriding OnModelCreating Class?

Sample:

protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{

```
     base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);

     //Map Entities to their tables.
     modelBuilder.Entity<ApplicationUser>().ToTable("MyUser");
```

}

you should let entity framework know that for MyUser Entity ApplicationUser entity should be used.

This link was very helpful for me : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=elfqejow5hM